# Choosing memory allocation api in linux kernel for allocating huge memory frequently

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have to allocate huge amount of memory frequently in my kernel driver. Which memory allocation api is better to use and why ?

Comment: what's wrong with `kmalloc` with `GFP_KERNEL` ?

Comment: @bolov kmalloc can allocate but it may be slower than caches(kmemcache), I just want to conform.

Comment: ok. I am was asking because I am just a beginner in linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need large allocations, `kmalloc()` is not a good idea, because once the physical address space has become fragmented, large `kmalloc()` allocations will frequently fail.

So `vmalloc()` / `vfree()` is most probably the way to go - unless you need to share the buffer with the hardware device, in which case look into the CMA (Contiguous Memory Allocator), `dma_alloc_from_contiguous()` / `dma_release_from_contiguous()`.